# Vertically scrolling. Horizontal movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm trying to find the code that is moving the page vertically and then moves horizontally while still scrolling vertically. I'm positive it's not Canvas, but I could be wrong.

Here is the example.

http://enso.readymag.com/architects-own-houses/10/

Comment: It is hard to say by looking via web inspector, but you must provide us with your JS files, at least any code related to `.content-bounds` and `animation-container force3d` which are the `div` elements that are being translated horizontally/vertically simultaneously. Look into your JS plugins to identify who is modifying these elements

Comment: "Scrolljacking" is one of the worst UX tricks to ever grace the web, and you really, really shouldn't try to imitate it.

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://joelb.me/scrollpath/?

Comment: It probably just blocks all your scroll events, and manually override them. Don't do this. This is terrible UX.

Comment: why would it block the scroll events ?..he just needs to listen to scroll events on window and decide wether user is scrolling up or down.

Comment: THanks for the quick reply. No actually I'm thinking about ways to present a 15000 word thesis as a design public so I'm looking at way to show it. This really helps though.

Comment: @Blazemonger...that sounds so dogmatic

Comment: As others suggested it might be a bad idea...but if you know what you are dooing, take a look at this : http://codepen.io/nishants/pen/jWVomQ

Answer (score 2):

Okay your approach seems terrible, but I get what you want to achieve.

You need to fix a container on the viewport, and animate it as scroll happens.

Like this :

```
var $target  = $(".slider").first(),
    currentPosition = 0,
    moveBy = function(scrolledBy){
        currentPosition += scrolledBy;
        $target.css("transform", "translateX(" + (currentPosition) + "px)")
    },
    lastScrollTop = 0 ;

$(window).bind("scroll",function(e){
    var scrolledBy = $(window).scrollTop() - lastScrollTop;
    moveBy(-scrolledBy);
    lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

find a demo [here](http://codepen.io/nishants/pen/qbqLjw) : http://codepen.io/nishants/pen/qbqLjw

**Do not even think of doing this with canvas**

Comment: Dawn, Chuckle...At this very moment I am thinking about using html5 canvas to create this [Meezio](https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath) effect. Upvote.

Comment: ha...BTW tried the demo http://joelb.me/scrollpath/, doesn't even work on chrome (mac-os)